# VK API - вопрос по users.get

Tags: vkontakte-api

Почему users.get работает и возвращает правильно записи только для user_ids в количестве меньше или равно 10. Если передать 11 и больше идентификаторов то она вернет "Incorrect signature: sid & secret authorization". Хотя в документации написано что максимальное количество идентификаторов 1000.

```
VK.api("users.get", {user_ids: [210700286, 210700200, 210700201], fields: ['photo_50']}, function (res) ())
```

Приложение IFrame.

Comment: Думаю, этот вопрос лучше задать в поддержке ВК

Comment: попробуйте сделать прямой GET-запрос через строку браузера и посмотрите поведение. у вас обертка, может быть дело в самой функции, которая реализует взаимодействие с VK API